# How to resize background image as needed

Tags: ios, uibutton, background-image

i'm trying to create an ui button with image and text.

What i need is simple:

an image centered on the first row and on another row a label centered.

So i've created an uibutton in my storyboard, set text and background in this way:

[image]

But the result isn't good for me.

This is what i have:

[image]

and this is what i need:

[image]

Can someone help me?

thanks!

**EDIT**

I've created a custom UIButton in this way:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuButton : UIButton
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *text;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "MenuButton.h"

@implementation MenuButton

@end
```

And in interface builder i create a view with class `MenuButton` addedd an image and a label and connecting to .h.

Now my question is:

How can i pass to that new button the image and the label in order to instantiate multiple "custom button" with different value inside?

Thanks!

Comment: the button is the outside rect?

Comment: yes, the entire button contains image and text

Comment: If you want these kind of behaviour i would recommend subclassing the UIButton, and add this behaviour

Comment: ok, i've understood that i need to override uibutton and create my button with image and text.. but how? :) have you got some guide about to create an uibutton with image and text? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a UIButton subclass.

1)

If you are using IB: then you can create 2 properties in the .h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *text
```

next you need to connect all the properties to the objects in the IB

If you are using code the remove the IBOutlet and move the properties to the .m

2)

Now all you need to do is manage the behaviour of the properties.

in IB, just add the autolayout constraints to the subclass and change their constant property value - check this [tutorial](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/42362079291/auto-layout-and-core-animation-auto-layout-was)

in code, you can do this by setting their frame with animation to make them larger/smaller

**EDIT**

Ok, after reading your update you need to change the subclass from `UIButton` to `UIView`.

This way you can add a `UIView` in your `storyboard` and add the `UImageView` & `UILable`. After doing so you can change the `UIView's` class to your subclass.

Then, click on the `UIView` and open the `connections inspector`. You will see the `IBOutlets` you have declared in th `UIView` subclass, you can just drag from the `connections inspector` to the `UIImageView` & `UILabel` to crete the connections